# How to access the child view controller from parent view controller in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a view controller which has a child view controller and I want to access that child view controller from its parent view controller.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: just hold a reference to that view controller, if you don't have a reference - then 
`view.subviews.first { $0 is YourViewController }`

Comment: @VitaliiShvetsov Sorry, but I didn't understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is ... (drum-roll......) ... it depends.. :-)

`NSViewController` & `UIViewController` have a `.parent` property.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621362-parent
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434491-parent

However, it is only populated if you're implementing the container-view-controller design pattern: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html (many uikit components use this pattern) IE:

```
aViewController.addChild(bViewController)
bViewControler.didMove(toParent: aViewController)
bViewController.parent // is aViewController
```

**Note: you'll have to manage the view stack yourself, this just ensures things like the lifecycle/drawing/resize/etc handlers happen in the correct order*

If you need to retain a reference to a view controller (child or otherwise), create a property on the child and set a reference to it, or use the container-view-controller design, it's very useful.

Cheers
- J

Comment: Got this error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeed03ff68)

Comment: @Simran I'm not sure how you're implementing this, but here's a screenshot of it in action. https://i.imgur.com/1QMpJT1.png

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but for simply explanation I think this example will be instructive for you.

Suppose that you are trying to achieve navigate your viewcontrollers and using navigation controller for that in a stack

```
   let parentVC = UIViewController()
   let childVC = UIViewController()

   parentVC.navigationController?.viewControllers.append(childVC)
   let childVCisHere = parentVC.navigationController?.viewControllers.first
```

Finally think about the analogy I established on **- GodFather -** family hieararchy

**Don Vito Corleone**, *he is the boss also father of the family* **parentVC**

**Sonny Corleone**, *he is dealing with dirty jobs, navigate childs behalf of family* **navigationController**

**Michael Corleone**, *he is little bro, people see him on the screen mostly* :) **childVC**

Comment: Also check this articles to get the concept, there are useful extensions in them and as well
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/child-view-controllers/
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-use-view-controller-containment

Comment: I tried but getting this error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeed03ff68)

Comment: no you can't I did it is working, try inside viewed load, I don't know how is your code so I have no idea why it happened